# Is there a preference rule for exec in xinitrc?

Tags: xinit

I have i3 installed as my primary window manager; now I want to test dwm. My xinitrc has only one line: `exec i3`. If I want dwm to launch and not i3 do I have to delete this line completely or do I have to just put `exec dwm` above this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xinitrc` file is a shell script.  The `exec` statement in a shell script says "replace this running program (the shell running the script) with the given program".  Assuming the given program can be run, the shell won't be around to run anything after the first `exec`; anything that comes after the first successful `exec` is effectively ignored.

To make it clear, I would comment out anything that you don't want to run by placing a `#` character in front of it:

```
# exec i3
exec dwm
```

That way, if you want/need to switch back, it's easy to remember what the previous value was.